# Why hidden TabBar in landscape mode shows a blank area?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm hiding tabbar when a particular View shows in landscape. It works fine but shows a white blank space below the view. Any idea how to fix this ?

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resize your current UIView:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; // Just for checking
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
```

You should change the height at your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

when you are pushing to other view,where you don't need the Tab bar just write it

```
twitDetObj=[[TwitDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"TwitDetail" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:twitDetObj animated:YES];
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
[twitDetObj release];
```

Comment: Does rotating a view means loading it ? I don't understand your point

Answer (score 0):

This thread resolved the blank space issue after hours of research: [hiding TabBar when rotating iPhone device to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164274/hiding-tabbar-when-rotating-iphone-device-to-landscape/1554637#1554637)