# White space in place of a hidden tab bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I use `UINavigationController` inside `UITabBarController` and one of the screens in my navigationcontroller is a `UIImageView`. When I want to show that image full screen I have to hide the navigation bar and tab bar. I'm able to hide the navigation bar correctly but when I hide the tab bar, it leaves 50px of white space. Any suggestion?

Comment: Self-contained samples are useful to understand what is going on. Try to edit your question. thank you.

Comment: Since iOS 8 all the "will-rotation-functions" are deprecated. [So for now my solution to handle this.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29772254/2242687

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you for all
I have found the best solution to my problem .

```
MyImageViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES ;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:MyImageViewController animated:YES];
```

It gave me the response I wanted .
Thank you for your share

Answer (score 2):

I think you can show it on model view controller.
Put modelviewcontroller over tabbarcontroller.

```
FullImageView*objFullImageView = [[FullImageView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FullImageView" bundle:nil];
objFullImageView.image = OriginalImage;
UINavigationController *tempNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objFullImageView] autorelease];
[objFullImageView release];
self.tabBarCtrl.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[self.tabBarCtrl presentModalViewController:tempNav animated:YES];
```

FullImageView.h

```
{  
    UIImage *image;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
```

FullImageView.m

```
@synthesize image;

viewDidLoad /ViewWillApper
{
    //Set image in your UIImageView    
}
```

Comment: You have to create a new class. then create object of that class and show that object as modelviewcontroller. I have edit my answer.

Comment: And you did not require to hide your navigation controller as well as tabbar.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing constraints.

I had a view in my tabbar viewController whose bottom constraint was given (=0) from Safe Area.bootom. This was causing white space at the bottom. Changing this constraint to (=0) from Superview.bottom solved my proble.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the height of your image view frame.

Comment: I did it already but it did not make anything . The problem is still exist .

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research, this thread resolved my blank space issue when hidding the tabbar: [hiding TabBar when rotating iPhone device to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164274/hiding-tabbar-when-rotating-iphone-device-to-landscape/1554637#1554637)

Answer (score 0):

It's been quite a long time since the original post, but I thought I could jump in and add my thoughts.

Another option would be to set the option `Hide bottom bar on push` directly within the Storyboard for all those controllers which are pushed within a navigation controller inside a tabbar controller. This works within iOS7 simulator/targets as well, both at 3.5" and 4".