# Hide UITabBar in landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

How does one hide the UITabBar programmatically?  It's been asked and answered multiple times on SO, but the answers seem to come in roughly two varieties:

1) Using a navigation controller, one can hide the next vc's tab bar before the push using hidesBottomBarWhenPushed property.  [Typical answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815690/hide-uitabbar).

2) Walk through the tabbar controller's view hierarchy and modify the tab bar's frame and/or visibility.  [Typical answer here](http://www.developers-life.com/hide-uitabbarcontrolleruitabbar-with-animation.html).

But both sorts of answers fall short, imo.  1) What if we need to hide the tab bar on the view we are on, say when rotating to landscape.  2) A half page of code waking through an Apple library's private view hierarchy is a. cumbersome, b. prone to unforseen breaking, c. possibly a blocker for app approval.

So what's an app to do?  Is the answer that it's not allowed?  Is there an apple document ref supporting that?  It would be a sad answer.  Imo, the rotation case is a legitimate reason for hiding the tab bar.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If this isn't answered by the time I get off work tonight, I'd love to share my code that does just what you're looking for.  Took me a bit of searching, and various attempts to make it actually work.  In my application I rotate into Landscape to hide the tab bar and nav bar, and show a full screen map UI element.  I'll post later if still needed.

Comment: That would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delayed response but I've pulled my code and you can see how I rotate my device to show a 'Map View' in full screen in landscape only.

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    [self hideTabBar:self.tabBarController];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.eventsMapView];
    self.eventsMapView.bounds = self.view.bounds;
    self.eventsMapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -208, self.view.frame.size.width, 300);
} else if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    [self showTabBar:self.tabBarController];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.eventsMapView];
}
```

}

And since we call methods within that to actually hide and show the tab bar, we need to define those methods in our .m file as well:

```
#pragma mark - Tab Bar Methods -

-(void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *)tabbarcontroller {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } else {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
        }
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];   
}

-(void)showTabBar:(UITabBarController *)tabbarcontroller {       
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } else {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 431)];
        }
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

If you're already within a Tab Bar Controller then you need to make sure every child (or individual tab ViewController) returns TRUE for orientation like below.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
return TRUE;
```

}

Hope this helps - if you have any questions leave a comment and I'll update my answer to show it off better.

Comment: +1 for sharing a workable answer, but I think it falls under the second category of inadequate solutions I mentioned because it manipulates the system's private hierarchy directly.   Thanks!

Comment: if you are willing to touch the tab bar directly, here's a couple of suggestions to improve the code you posted:  1) get the tabBar without the search - from a contained view controller you can say:  tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar.  2) use [UIView animateWithDuration... methods for cleaner animation code, 3) avoid literal floats in the framing like this: tabBar.frame = CGRectOffset(tabBar.frame, 0.0, sign*tabBar.frame.size.height);  where sign is +1 to hide and -1 to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some useful code [here](http://www.developers-life.com/hide-uitabbarcontrolleruitabbar-with-animation.html). You can call hideTabbar from your shouldrotate: method

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, that was the link I posted as an example of a not particularly good solution.

Answer (score 0):

2021 answer. Xcode 12.
Create a new layout for when in Landscape mode. in the below picture, I created wAny hCompact (hC) attribute and then set it as hidden.

[image]